# Duda estructura de control (Do - While) JavaScript

Tags: javascript

No funciona la estructura de control de este codigo, agradeceria me ayudaran a encontrar el error, muchas gracias

```
var ford_fiesta = 5000;
var ford_focus = 9000;

do {
    alert("Ingresa codigo 01/FIESTA para FORD FIESTA o codigo 02/FOCUS para FORD FOCUS");
    codigo = prompt("Ingresa tu eleccion");
} while (codigo != "01" || codigo != "02" || codigo.toUpperCase() != "FIESTA" || codigo.toUpperCase() != "FOCUS");
```

Answer (score 3):

Tambien puedes hacerlo así:

```javascript
var ford_fiesta = 5000;
var ford_focus = 9000;
var codigo
do {
    alert("Ingresa codigo 01/FIESTA para FORD FIESTA o codigo 02/FOCUS para FORD FOCUS");
    codigo = prompt("Ingresa tu eleccion")
} while (codigo != "01" && codigo != "02" && codigo.toUpperCase() != "FIESTA" && codigo.toUpperCase() != "FOCUS");
```

Tal como dice la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) de `do... while`:

> La sentencia (hacer mientras) crea un bucle que ejecuta una sentencia
> especificada, hasta que la condición de comprobación se evalúa como
> falsa. La condición se evalúa después de ejecutar la sentencia, dando
> como resultado que la sentencia especificada se ejecute al menos una
> vez.

O sea, la condición debe ser `falsa` para salir del bucle. En tu caso siempre era verdadera porque o bien no era 01 (verdad) , o bien no era 02 (verdad) o bien no era FIESTA (verdad) o bien no era FOCUS (verdad), y eso siempre era verdadero, porque nunca podia cumplir todas estas proposiones a la vez y ser falso, tal como se aprecia en la siguiente tabla.

Fijarse en la [tabla de la verdad de la disyunción](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_de_verdad#Disyunci.C3.B3n) (OR):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi propuesta de solución se basa en el operador lógico AND, simbolizado con `&&`, para establecer la siguiente lógica:

```
(codigo != "01" && codigo != "02" && codigo.toUpperCase() != "FIESTA" && codigo.toUpperCase() != "FOCUS")
```

que escrito lógicamente seria:

> Si el código no es 01 (verdad), ni 02 (verdad), ni FIESTA (verdad), ni FOCUS (verdad), entonces se cumple
> la condición como verdadera (true).

Por lo tanto, a la que una de sus proposiciones sea **falsa**, la sentencia lógica pasará a ser falsa, y el while terminará.

Fijarse en esta [tabla de la verdad de la conjunción](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_de_verdad#Conjunci.C3.B3n) (AND) para entender que, tal solo que haya un *falso*, es decir, haya una coincidencia entre el valor recogido en el prompt y cualquiera de estas proposiciones, la sentencia completa se evaluará como **falsa**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema de lógica.

Imagina por ejemplo que el usuario introduce `01`:

1. Entra a la primera condición del `while` y pregunta:
   ¿`codigo != "01"`?  -> `Falso`, porque son iguales.
2. Paso a la segunda condición, ¿`codigo != "02"`?  -> Verdadero. Entonces como tengo al menos un verdadero, el resultado de los `||` es verdadero, entro nuevamente al ciclo.

Eso te va a pasar siempre. Cuando se cumpla una, la otra no se va a cumplir, dando como resultado un ciclo infinito. ¿La solución? La negación de las igualdades:

```js
let codigo = ""
do {
    alert("Ingresa codigo 01/FIESTA para FORD FIESTA o codigo 02/FOCUS para FORD FOCUS");
    codigo = prompt("Ingresa tu eleccion");
} while (!(codigo == "01" || codigo == "02" || codigo.toUpperCase() == "FIESTA" || codigo.toUpperCase() == "FOCUS"))
```

Comment: La solución más fácil en realidad es sustituir los `or` por `and`... Ya que lo que quieres en realidad es que se mantenga dentro cuando sea diferente de 01 Y diferente de 02. Vamos, es la manera más fácil de leerlo. Recordad que el código se escribe una vez... pero se lee muchas más. El código fácil de leer es código fácil de mantener ;)

Comment: @Benito-B tienes toda la razón. No se cómo no se me ocurrió cuando escribía la respuesta, supongo que la lógica negativa a veces enreda un poco. De cualquier manera ya @masterguru dió una muy buena respuesta. Dejaré esta solución de este modo como otra posible opción aunque indudablemente con `&&` es mucho más legible.